# Ionic publish Ios application

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, publish

I have published the android version of my ionic application. But when I try to register the appId on the apple developer website, it throws this error

```
An App ID with Identifier 'com.xx.app' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

Am I supposed to manually change it for iOS and android ?

Comment: Yes you need to change Identifier as the One is not available.

Comment: but if I change it, won't it affect the published app in Android if I upload a newer version

Comment: Android and iOS are different apps with different App Store, AppID is an internal identifier which is not exposed to users, its you who will maintain it, you can always have different appids for Android and iOS it won't affect any of them, what is important is the AppName, it should be same, check if thats available.

Comment: Can you guide me, how do I write the different identifiers in my config.xml file